# Gradle build failed with error Failed to resolve: com.android.support

Tags: android, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I am trying to build the old code but the `gradle` sync is failed giving error :

> Failed to resolve: com.android.support.

I have researched the problem and tried implementing them in my code but any of them didn't worked.My `gradle` looks as follows:

```
      apply plugin: 'com.android.application'

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'
    defaultConfig {
        applicationId "com.tex"
        minSdkVersion 15
        targetSdkVersion 27
        versionCode 1
        versionName "1.0"
        testInstrumentationRunner "android.support.test.runner.AndroidJUnitRunner"
        vectorDrawables.useSupportLibrary = true
    }
    buildTypes {
        release {
            minifyEnabled false
            proguardFiles getDefaultProguardFile('proguard-android.txt'), 'proguard-rules.pro'
        }
    }
}

dependencies {
    implementation fileTree(dir: 'libs', include: ['*.jar'])

    implementation project(':slideMenuLibrary')
    implementation('com.github.nkzawa:socket.io-client:0.3.0') {
        exclude group: 'org.json', module: 'json'
    }

    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test:runner:1.0.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'com.android.support.test.espresso:espresso-core:3.0.2'
    implementation 'com.android.support.constraint: constraint-layout: 1.0.2'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-maps:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-analytics:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.google.android.gms:play-services-gcm:10.2.1'
    implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.koushikdutta.ion:ion:2.+'
    implementation 'com.android.support:design:27.1.1'
    implementation 'com.squareup.picasso:picasso:2.5.2'
    implementation 'com.victor:lib:1.0.4'
    implementation 'com.afollestad.material-dialogs:core:0.8.6.2'
    implementation 'com.github.lzyzsd:circleprogress:1.1.0@aar'
    implementation 'com.loopj.android:android-async-http:1.4.9'
    implementation 'com.wdullaer:materialdatetimepicker:2.4.0'
    implementation 'org.apache.commons:commons-lang3:3.3.2'
    androidTestImplementation 'junit:junit:4.12'
}
```

My project build.gradle file looks as follows:

```
 buildscript {
        repositories {
            jcenter()
            google()

        }
        dependencies {
            classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'

            // NOTE: Do not place your application dependencies here; they belong
            // in the individual module build.gradle files
        }
    }

    allprojects {
        repositories {
            mavenLocal()
            mavenCentral()
            jcenter()
            google()

        }
    }

    task clean(type: Delete) {
        delete rootProject.buildDir
    }
```

The gradle file of the library is as follows:

```
 buildscript {
    repositories {
        google()
        jcenter()
        mavenLocal()
        mavenCentral()

    }
    dependencies {
        classpath 'com.android.tools.build:gradle:3.1.3'
    }
}
apply plugin: 'com.android.library'

dependencies {
    implementation 'com.android.support:support-v4:27.1.1'
}

android {
    compileSdkVersion 27
    buildToolsVersion '27.0.3'

    defaultConfig {
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion 27
    }

    sourceSets {
        main {
            java.srcDirs = ['src']
            resources.srcDirs = ['src']
            aidl.srcDirs = ['src']
            renderscript.srcDirs = ['src']
            res.srcDirs = ['res']
            assets.srcDirs = ['assets']

            manifest.srcFile 'AndroidManifest.xml'
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: Replace api with implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'

Comment: Are you using Windows?

Comment: Yes windows 10 @parekhkruti26

Comment: Actually there is a problem when using AS with Windows. It, in some cases gives this type of error when `google()` is placed below others

Comment: tried keeping google() above. the problem is still the same @parekhkruti26

Answer (score 0):

Add below in your root build.gradle file inside allprojects :

```
   repositories {
    mavenLocal()
    mavenCentral()
    maven {                                  // <-- Add this
        url 'https://maven.google.com/' 
        name 'Google'
    }
}
```

If you're using Android Plugin for Gradle 3.0.0 or latter version

```
repositories {
  mavenLocal()
  mavenCentral()
  google()        //---> Add this
}
```

and inject dependency in this way :

```
implementation 'com.android.support:appcompat-v7:27.1.1'
```

Comment: I have edited the question..tried the way you directed but the problem is still the same @Sahil

Comment: i still see 'api' instead of 'implementation' in your dependency deceleration in gradle.

Comment: I had implemented as you have directed and I have edited the code but the problem is same